# Z-transform's region of convergence

Tags: z-transform

I am learning Z trasnform.The region of convergence is extremely important for a Z-transform.The region of convergence is extremely important for a Z-transform,but i encouter a problem that when i calculate Z-transform of convolution of two sequences ，i have no idea how to determine its region of convergence. The Z-transform of this sequnces (as belows) has three poles , and I haven't expanded this sequence into series form, and I can't use methods such as ratio discrimination to discriminate series convergence.
Should I expand this sequence into series form to use methods in convergence of series？
One step further ,there is any general way to solve Z-transform's region of convergence?

$$y(n)=x_1(n+3)*x_2(-n+1)$$
$$x_1(n)=(\frac{1}{2})^{n}*u(n)$$
$$x_2(n)=(\frac{1}{3})^{n}*u(n)$$

Comment: Are you talking about the unilateral transform, and do you really mean convolution in the above or multiplication?

Comment: @copper.hat This is the Z-transform of the convolution

Comment: That answers neither question/

Comment: @copper.hat I don’t understand,sorry .but this question is to calculate Y(Z)